# Set height MultilineText RadDataForm iOS Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to style the Raddataform type="multilinetext". This works perfectly fine for Android by setting the height. However, the height is not affecting the style in iOS.

How can I create a multi-line field in RadDataForm for iOS with a specified height?

The same issue holds for type="text" by the way.

```
<TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="myname">
    <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="MultilineText"></TKPropertyEditor>
</TKEntityProperty>


RadDataForm DataFormEditorCore {
   height: 50;
}

RadDataForm PropertyEditor[type='MultilineText'] DataFormEditorCore {
    height: 80;
}
```

Both styles don't affect iOS.

Comment: Can you share some sample code to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I updated my initial post with the code

Comment: As per docs setting height from CSS is not supported for DataFormEditorCore, Android is always flexible with layouts so it seems just worked. You may try to set the height on the iOS component natively. Refer advanced styling section of the docs for examples.

Comment: Do you have a more specific link? I can't find any section that describes to style iOS components natively.

Comment: Sure, here you go - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/DataForm/dataform-styling#styling-native-components